# Function that accepts two lists of predicates and elements list and partitions the elements list accordingly

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, predicate, partition, mini-language

i want to write a function that accepts two  lists of predicates functions and elements list and  returns all the members in the original list that hold all the predicates in pre1_list and delete the members in the original list that unhold all the predicates in pre2_list

i am writing this code in a language called mini lisp , it's similar to lisp but more simple ,but that doesn't matter , i just want help on how to do such a thing ? an idea of how to implement such code !

how i am thinking to do it : (just the beginning of my idea)

```
(defun get_pred_1_not_2 (pre1_list pre2_list list)
  (cond
    ((null list) NIL)
      ; return all the members in the original list that hold all the predicates in pre1_list
    (pre1_list (get_pred_1_not_2 (cdr pre1_list) pre2_list (filter_pre list (car pre1_list))))
      ; delete all the members in the original list that unhold all the predicates in pre2_list
    (pre2_list (get_pred_1_not_2 pre1_list (cdr pre2_list) ;.... (
```

where `filter_pre` is a function that returns all the element from the list that holds predications giving to it

i hope someone could help ! as this function is really deficult to write and i don't want to just give up
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try building the whole solution all at once. Instead proceed by building the building blocks for yourself, function by function, for simple enough tasks so that each function is easy to write. That's the "functional programming" approach.

Start with the simple `filter` function for one predicate. Then modify it to have your `filter-not`.

Then use them to implement `filter-ps` and `filter-not-ps`.

Alternatively, turn your list of predicates into one predicate by writing `all-ps` and `all-ps-not` functions.

The produced *predicate* will work with *one* element at a time, so you can use it with the simple `filter` to get what you want, with two calls to `filter` -- first with the result of `all-ps` applied to your first predicates list; second with the result of `all-ps-not` applied to your second predicates list.

*edit:* if you *delete* all elements for which all predicates "unhold" i.e. return false, you are left with all the elements for which at least one of the predicates returns true. So you might as well say, for the second part of the task, that you want to *keep* all elements for which at least one of the predicates hold. Still the same general guidelines apply, just that instead of defining `all-ps-not` you need to define `at-least-one-of-ps`, or perhaps name it `some-ps`.

Comment: delete all the members in the original list that unhold all the predicates in pre2_list and       ; keep all the members in the original list that hold all the predicates in pre1_list